# passing data in querystring when using tiles

Tags: spring, query-string, tiles2

I am using tiles2 and spring in my project. When i am redirecting from spring controller to a jsp(the jsp page is mapped in tiles.xml file) page using query string like:

```
return "showRes.jsp?subSucc=ok";
```

it shows me:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'showRes.jsp?subSucc=ok'
```

I think this is wrong way to passing data using query string.
Please tell me how can i do this.

Thanks
Shams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that `return "showRes.jsp?subSucc=ok";` statment should return the name of a jsp and it is NOT a URL.

The normal Spring way to pass values is a jsp is to use a Model Map (of course there are some other ways, but this is the easysest to describe one).

Have a look at the [ModelAndView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) and [Model](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html) class. Create an instance of it, set the view name and add your parameter, and then return it instead of the String.

```
Model model = new Model();
model.addAttribute("subSucc","ok");
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("showRes.jsp", model);
//may without ".jsp" postfix - this depends on your configuration
return modelAndView;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Model and ModelAndView. But i want to pass data as a querystring so that i can do something in javascript. Is there any way to pass value in querystring??

Comment: @shams haque: I think you need to pass the values from the ModelMap in a javascript variable within you jsp: `<script type="text/javascript">
  var myValue = '<c:out value="subSucc" />';
</script>`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have done it by using object of ModelAndView, mav.addObject("subSucc", "shams"); and on jsp: <script> var myValue = '${subSucc}'; </script>. The <c:out> is not working in script. May be it can also work with ModelMap.